# Can only cast 38 votes (not daily limit of 40), any ideas?

Tags: support, badges, voting

So, I'm being taunted with the promise of the Vox Populi badge, the site even suggests that I "Go get it!" But when I try to do the last two votes I'm told "Daily vote limit reached; vote again in 18 hours."

Any idea what could be going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a design feature in the Stackexchange network. See [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117687/how-to-get-vox-populi-badge-when-you-can-no-longer-vote-after-32-votes) and the ones linked in.

Comment: Thank you! Did you find that by going meta-meta? I didn't see anything relevant when I composed the question, but I suppose that was looking only at Meta Bicycles.

Comment: And for the benefit of anybody who comes here looking for the answer, the gist of the linked threads is that the 40 vote limit is dynamic. It is the aggregate of votes on questions and votes on answers. The more questions you vote on the better you chance of getting all 40 and the Vox Populi badge.

Comment: Yep. You get 30 votes. If you use 10 of them on questions, then you still have 30 votes. When you have only 5 votes left, you get a countdown. At that point voting for questions doesn't change the countdown, so you really have to use at least 10 votes on questions in the first 25 votes you cast.